# How do I sort a Python Dictionary by a named value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, named

I have a dictionary 'dict' like so:

```
{'Name1' : {'value1' : 3.0, 'value2' : 1.4, 'Index' : 2 },  
 'Name2' : {'value1' : 5.0, 'value2' : 0.1, 'Index' : 1 },  
 ...
}
```

How would I sort the dictionary into a new one, based on the 'Index' field?
So I want to end up as:

```
{'Name2' : {'value1' : 5.0, 'value2' : 0.1, 'Index' : 1 },  
 'Name1' : {'value1' : 3.0, 'value2' : 1.4, 'Index' : 2 },  
 
 ...
}
```

I have tried

```
new_dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x['Index'])
```

but Python objects to the str as the slice.

Apart from the clunky method of iterating through and appending each item to a new dictionary what is the recommended method please?

Comment: What you have shown are not syntactically valid Python dictionaries. Did you mean to write `:` instead of `=`?

Comment: You can't sort dictionaries. You can create a dictionary in a particular order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant:

```
{'Name1' : {'value1': 3.0, 'value2': 1.4, 'Index': 2 },  
 'Name2' : {'value1': 5.0, 'value2': 0.1, 'Index': 1 },  
 ...
}
```

`dict.items()` iterates over *pairs* of keys and values, so in your `lambda` expression, `x` is not a dictionary like `{'value1': ...}`, but a tuple like `('Name2', {'value1': ...})`.

You can change `lambda x: x['Index']` to `lambda x: x[1]['Index']` (i.e., first get the second item of the tuple (which should now be the nested dictionary), then get the `'Index'` value in that dictionary.

Next, `sorted()` will give you a list of key, value pairs (which may be appropriate). If you really want a dictionary, you can change `sorted(...)` to `dict(sorted(...))`, with two caveats:

- In older Python versions this will lose the sorting again (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)).
- Don't use `dict` as a variable name, otherwise you will shadow the built-in `dict` constructor and will get a type error "object is not callable".

Answer (score 2):

Python dict is a hashed associative container, it cannot be sorted.

Python 3 dict is insertion-ordered, so if you sort a copy of items collections of the original dictionary and comprehend it back into a dict it will be in the order you need.

```
x = {
    'Name2': {'value1': 5.0, 'value2': 0.1, 'Index': 1},
    'Name1': {'value1': 3.0, 'value2': 1.4, 'Index': 2}
}

y = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['Index'])}
```

Also, have you seen [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: It is ordered though.

Comment: In Python 3.7+ `dict` is ordered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @PeterWood - let me update the answer and make it clear, tx

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html